# is there a local github for teamwork? (not in cloud)

Tags: github, local

me and my friend are developing new code and we want to maintaine from time to time.
we looking for sodtware or service that can provide us what github and his "friends" are providing but we dont want to store our code on the cloud or in the web.
a software that can provide us something like when someone is working on the code so no one else can work on this in the same time' you know what I mean...

can anyone recommand about software or service like this?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes you can. Try [Atlassian Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository).

Comment: So basically, you're looking for a self-hosted version control system?

Comment: Alejandro ,yes something like this

Comment: Arcteezy, in this service I dont need to store my code on cloud?

Comment: I suggest you to read [Git Book Chapter 4: Git on the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), where it explains how you can setup your own Git server, in case you prefer to work on a private network. Note that having a web interface is not the same as working with Git in the web.

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab is easy to [install on a Linux](https://about.gitlab.com/install/) server.
It offers a lot of features on the open version, it is what you're searching for I guess.
The Gitlab on the cloud is not free, it is similar to Github, but don't worry you won't have to pay unless you need advanced features (out of issues, PR, basic CI, hooks...) https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/#self-managed

Answer (score 0):

First of all you i have to define what you really need. It seems that your are looking for a remote solution that enables you and friends to work together on common code and at the sametime you don't want a "cloud" solution.

By "cloud" i guest you want to say not in internet? If it is so; why don't you try a personnal **Gitlab** server, hosted on a server in your home or friend's one. If you have serious unix skill this is something that you can envisage or try a private cloud solution as **bitbucket**.

Comment: I went to this site but its interface is on the internet.  I look for something like visual sourcesafe' did you hear about this software?

Comment: Ok i see, didn't know visual sourcesafe.